# Remove white space above first image AMP coding

Tags: html, amp-html

I am a bit green so I'll explain as best as I can.

The first image on all of my AMP website has a white gap between the title bar and header image that makes it all awful. I tried several approaches like

```
<style amp-custom>
    div.img-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>
```

in the head, followed by

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
<amp-img
    src="https://myimg.png"
    width="950"
    height="600"
    layout="responsive"
>
</amp-img>
</div>
```

in the body, but doesn't seem to work. I tried following other answers, like the one about vertical positioning but nothing again. Can anybody explain where I go wrong, please?
The page in question is https://crystalhealinglondon.com/amp. I am using WP AMP plugin but am de-activating it in some pages to make my own formatting.  Could be this the problem?
Many thanks for your help

Comment: Please link to the page. The snipped you posted looks good, the problem must be somewhere else. See this fiddle for example https://jsfiddle.net/p6wuca8v/

Comment: Stylesuxx tried to follow the example and modified the coding accordingly but the stupid space is still there! thank you for your suggestion

Comment: You have a lot of empty paragraphs before your image. Your AMP image itself is completely fine. Simply remove the paragraphs between your h1 tag and img-wrapper and you should be good to go.

Comment: Hi @stylesuxx, I get your point but I have no paragraphs at all...\\\ <style amp-custom>
div.img-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<div class="img-wrapper">
<amp-img
  src="https://crystalhealinglondon.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Banner-central.png"
  width="600"
  height="400"
  layout="responsive"
>
</amp-img> \\\ is the entire snippet. I found out that WP AMP plugin page title overruns my coding so I removed it. It looks much better but the space is still there.

Comment: Yes you do have them ;-) Inspect the source of your page. If you did not add them, something else in your CMS is adding them. Especially the one with the multiple br tags is the problem.